# Fitting a theoretical distribution to a sampled empirical CDF with scipy stats

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, cdf

I have a plot for the CDF distribution of packet losses. I thus do not have the original data or the CDF model itself but samples from the CDF curve. (The data is extracted from plots published in literature.)

I want to find which distribution and with what parameters offers the closest fit to the CDF samples.

I've seen that Scipy stats distributions offer fit(data) method but all examples apply to raw data points. PDF/CDF is subsequently drawn from the fitted parameters. Using fit with my CDF samples does not give sensible results.

Am I right in assuming that fit() cannot be directly applied to data samples from an empirical CDF?

What alternatives could I use to find a matching known distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. When you say you have a CDF, what does that mean? Do you have some data points, or the function itself? It would be helpful if you could post more information or some sample data.

If you have some data points and know the distribution its not hard to do using scipy. If you don't know the distribution, you could just iterate over all distributions until you find one which works reasonably well.

We can define functions of the form required for `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. I.e., the first argument should be `x`, and then the other arguments are parameters.

I use this function to generate some test data based on the CDF of a normal random variable with a bit of added noise.

```
n = 100
x = np.linspace(-4,4,n)
f = lambda x,mu,sigma: scipy.stats.norm(mu,sigma).cdf(x)

data = f(x,0.2,1) + 0.05*np.random.randn(n)
```

Now, use `curve_fit` to find parameters.

```
mu,sigma = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f,x,data)[0]
```

This gives output

```
>> mu,sigma
0.1828320963531838, 0.9452044983927278
```

We can plot the original CDF (orange), noisy data, and fit CDF (blue) and observe that it works pretty well.
[image: true CDF, noisy data, recovered CDF]

Note that `curve_fit` can take some additional parameters, and that the output gives additional information about how good of a fit the function is.

Answer (score 0):

@tch Thank you for the answer. I read on the technique and successfully applied it. I wanted to apply the fit to all continuous distribution supported by scipy.stats so I ended up doing the following:

```
fitted = []
failed = []

for d in dist_list:

    dist_name = d[0] #fetch the distribution name
    dist_object = getattr(ss, dist_name) #fetch the distribution object
    param_default = d[1] #fetch the default distribution parameters

    # For distributions with only location and scale set those to the default loc=0 and scale=1
    if not param_default:
        param_default = (0,1)

    # Computed parameters of fitted distribution
    try:
        param,cov = curve_fit(dist_object.cdf,data_in,data_out,p0=param_default,method='trf')

        # Only take distributions which do not result in zero covariance as those are not a valid fit
        if np.any(cov):
            fitted.append((dist_name,param),)

    # Capture which distributions are not possible to be fitted (variety of reasons)       
    except (NotImplementedError,RuntimeError) as e:
        failed.append((dist_name,e),)
        pass
```

In the above, the empirical cdf distribution is captured in `data_out` which holds the sampled cdf values for a range of `data_in` data points. The list `dist_list` holds for each distribution in `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` the name of the distribution as first element and a list of the default parameters as second element. Default parameters I extract from `scipy.stats._distr_params`.

Some distributions cannot be fitted and raise an error. I keep those is `failed` list.

Finally, I generate a list `fitted` which holds for each successfully fitted distribution the estimated parameters.